# Is there an analytic function $f$ in the open unit disc such that $|f(z)|=e^{|z|}$ therein?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Is there an analytic function $f$ in the open unit disc such that $|f(z)|=e^{|z|}$ therein?

**My try**:

Suppose such  a function exists .Then $|f(0)|=e^0=1$ Also $|f|\ge 0$.

Now $e^{|z|}$ attains its minimum value i.e. $1$ at $0$. Thus $|f(z)|\ge 1$

I was trying to use the minimum modulus theorem which states that if $f$ is a non- constant analytic function such that $|f|$ attains  its minimum value in an interior point of the unit disc then $f$ is constant.

Here $|f|$ attains its minimum value at $0$ which is an interior point  of the unit disc and thus  $f$ is constant which is false as $|f|=e^{|z|}$.

Thus no such analytic function exists.

Comment: You are right. You should add that $f$ is nonzero on the open disc, so that you can take its reciprocal and apply the maximum modulus theorem, but this is immediate, since $|f(z)|=e^{|z|}>0$.

Comment: Thank you very much @Jean-ClaudeArbaut

Comment: "if f  is a non- constant analytic function such that |f| attains its minimum value in an interior point of the unit disc then f is constant." You need to say f is never 0 for this

Answer (score 0):

This is a community wiki answer to notice that this question was answered in comments and remove the question from the unanswered list -- the answer is yes, the OP's proof is correct.

Comment: The OP's statement "If |$f|$ attains its minimum in the interior of the unit disc then $f$ is constant" is incorrect. It is only correct if $f$ is never $0$ in the open unit disc, as stated in the comment by zhw on  Apr.5/16.

Comment: Which follows immediately from the condition $|f| = e^{|z|}$. Whether or not to call the OP's argument "correct" with this detail omitted comes down to a question of how rigorously his or her course is graded; there is no substantive issue.